Night Light not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and Night Light is not working on the notebook screen, only on the extended screen. It doesn't work neither with Wayland or Xorg. My notebook is an Acer with AMD Ryzen 7 5700U.
I've already tried several tips given on forums and I've also consulted ChatGPT and Claude several times to help me, but no response has resolved my problem with the Night Light on the notebook screen.
Is anyone out there experiencing the same problem? How can I solve it?

Can you open Settings -> Color -> click the down facing arrow of your notebook screen (Built-In Screen) and see if it has a profile? If not, add a new one.

Wow!! @BeastOfCaerbannog, It solved my problem, I didn't imagine that, thank you very much!

This problem occurs because the color profile for your screen is missing and seems to occur when you upgrade from a previous installation and not when you do a clean install. It has happened to me as well on Fedora, but managed to solve it by adding a new color profile to the monitor that Night Light doesn't work on.
Here is my solution for the same issue I had asked about in Fedora Discussion (Night Light not working on Fedora 37):

I finally managed to solve this! It seems that after the upgrade, the color profiles for both my laptop and external monitor were disabled and were shown as Not calibrated in Settings → Color (see screenshot below, where I have already added a color profile for the external monitor but not for the laptop screen):

To add a profile, select the screen and click Add Profile. Then select a color profile from the Add Profile window that opens and click Add:

Night Light works properly after that.

